# How to detect if app is opened from website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React web application, and when user clicks on a button, a want to open Android/iOS application if it's installed. If not, I want to redirect to Play/App Store.

From the code below, when the user clicks on the button and if he has an installed application, that application will open (and that's ok), but then if he clicks on the back button in application, it will return him to the web where the Store will already be open because the function for redirecting to the store will be called after 3 seconds.

My question is, is there any way to detect if application is installed/opened so I don't get redirected to the store? Or is there other way to write this logic?

```
const navigateHandler = () => {
    if (isAndroid) {
      const url = 'example://example.mysite.eu/login';
      window.location.replace(url);

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace(
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.example'
        );
      }, 3000);
    } else if (isIOS) {
      window.location.replace('example://');

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace(
          'https://apps.apple.com/rs/app/example/id?itsct=apps_box_badge&amp;'
        );
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      navigate('/login', { replace: true });
    }
  };
```